# "I have no clue" vs. "I haven't a clue" vs. "I am clueless"

Tags: difference, phrase-usage

Is there a difference between the phrase

> I have no clue...

and

> I haven't a clue...

as well as

> I am clueless...

For instance if someone said:

> What is wrong with this?

Which of these could be used to answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not a fan of Ngrams, so my answer is based on personal opinion and experience.

Although I suppose that the three phrases would be perfectly understood in context, if I were to use one of them I'd go for the first one (***I have no clue***) or for a modified version of the second (***I don't have a clue*** or ***I haven't got a clue***).

I wouldn't use the second phrase as it is because in negative sentences the verb *have* is normally used either in conjunction with *got*, thus being an auxiliary, or preceded by *"don't"/"doesn't"/"didn't"* as any other verb.

As for *clueless*, OALD states that it is an informal, disapproving adjective which means "very stupid; not able to understand or do something", which is a deviation from the meaning of the previous sentences.

Comment: "I haven't a clue" is idiomatic and colloquial, almost certainly a shortening of "I haven't got a clue".  "I have no clue" sounds more formal.  But any of these would be understood to mean that you have no idea.  Correct about "clueless"; avoid it!

Comment: There's also a trivial informal: "No clue" or stronger "Not a clue!"

Comment: More than that: clueless is a description of a person's character not a word applied to a specific instance of not having a clue.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, all of those three are suitable answers.

*I have no clue* and *I haven't a clue* have the same meaning, but *I haven't a clue* seems to be more used according to [this Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%20have%20no%20clue,I%20haven%27t%20a%20clue&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) (blue line = *I have no clue*, red line = *I haven't a clue* - which Google changes to *I have not a clue*).

[image]

*I am clueless* will probably be understood by most people, even though *clueless* has some negative conotations of stupidity.